# Remove MMS and "Unmanage all" menu option

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I'm trying to get rid of MMS and clicked on "Unmanage all" menu option. After that MMS was displayed panel with multiple changes listed and button "Confirm and Deploy".

Why has it asked me to deploy changes when I'm trying to put my Mongo cluster in unmanaged by MMS state? Can I keep my Mongo settings as is and just to unmanage it?

Comment: By MMS, I assume you mean MongoDB Cloud Manager? The "Confirm and deploy" in this case is expected: the action you are confirming is unmanaging your environment.

Comment: No, it is not expected. MMS listed multiple changes related to removal or replicas configs, users removal ,... etc and it asks for "Confirm and deploy".

Comment: [Unmanaging a deployment](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/unmanage-deployment/) should only be removing the automation agents. However, if you have any concerns you should [create a support issue](https://cloud.mongodb.com/support) from your Cloud Manager account.